# How to get the smaller number of the inputs given by user?

Tags: math, numbers

I want to get the smaller number out of two user defined inputs.
For example:

```
1+1/2=1
```

**It should have two inputs:**

```
N,M=N
where N<M
```

I need a `mathematical expression` not a `function/code` like:

```
math.min(1,2)
```

Comment: Mod, Abs, √, ~, col, sin is allowed.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `abs`, the absolute value? Also, what do you call "mod"? The "modulus operator" behaves differently on different languages, when it is given negative numbers; and in your case that difference is going to be extremely relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the max{x,y}=x+y+|x−y|/2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429622/show-that-the-max-x-y-fracxyx-y2)

Comment: Yes but how to calculate min

Comment: With a minus somewhere instead of a plus; I'll let you read the page I linked and think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks You @Stef

Here is the Solution:
(X+Y-|X-Y|)/2

For Programmers: (X+Y-abs(X-Y))/2

Answer (score 0):

Try using comparison operators `> <`

Comment: It's x+y-|x-y|/2